# Opencv on mac include error

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, include

I installed opencv on my mac mountain lion using the mac port. Then I wrote a OpenCV_util.cc file that has:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

When I tried to compile it with `g++ OpenCV_util.cc`, I got the following error:

```
OpenCV_util.h:1:16: error: cv.h: No such file or directory
OpenCV_util.h:2:19: error: cvaux.h: No such file or directory
OpenCV_util.h:3:21: error: highgui.h: No such file or directory
```

Then I used

```
g++ OpenCV_util.cc -I /opt/local/include/opencv -L /opt/local/lib
```

The compiler found cv.h, cvaux.h, and highgui.h.
However, I got the following error:

```
In file included from OpenCV_util.h:1,
                 from OpenCV_util.cc:1:
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:33: error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64:33: error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

...... (A lot of errors like this)

I checked /opt/local/include/opencv2/core/, all the files were there. I think it's because in cv.h, it has:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

but not the absolute path.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should include `/opt/local/include/opencv`. You probably should just use this path: `/opt/local/include/` and use opencv or opencv2 where needed when using `#include`
For example

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
```

and something like:

```
g++ OpenCV_util.cc -I /opt/local/include/ -L /opt/local/lib
```